# WordPress: Get posts from two custom fields in meta query

Tags: php, wordpress, meta-query

I'm using a Custom Post Type to store recipes.
Every recipe is related to certain products and categories.

In a product I want to display recipes related to it.
So first I want to show recipes which have the product ID in the custom field `recipe_related_products` and after that I want to show recipes which have the current product category in the custom field `recipe_related_product_cats`.

I'm using the ACF relationship field for that.

Here's my code:

```
$recipes = get_posts(array(
    'post_type' => 'recipes',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key'     => 'recipe_related_products',
            'value'   => '"' . get_the_ID() . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
        array(
            'key'     => 'recipe_related_product_cats',
            'value'   => '"' . $cat_id . '"',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
));
```

The code shows only recipes from the field `recipe_related_products`.
It seems that `'relation' => 'OR'` has no effect.

If I remove the first array from the `meta_query` I get the recipes which are in the `recipe_related_product_cats`.

Is the `'relation' => 'OR'` the problem?
It seems that booth meta queries are correct but they don't work together?!

To get the current ID from the product I'm using this code:

```
$cat_list = wp_get_post_terms($product->get_id(),'product_cat',array('fields'=>'ids'));
$cat_id = (int)$cat_list[0];
```

Comment: Are you trying to combine two queries or what? Can you write the actual SQL query that you would expect to work for you?  What you have now would be like, `select from posts AND ((meta query 1) or (meta query 2))`

Comment: I try to combine them. I want to show recipes which have the procutd Ids in the meta field or the category ID of the product. It is possible that only one is true but in most cases both meta field would have values. I'm not sure how to write a SQL query for that :(

Comment: How are stored datas in recipe_related_products and recipe_related_product_cats fields ?

Comment: As ID's. If it's not easy possible, I could use two loops to get the same result. I thought there was an error in my code.